# Passing dynamic variable in meta tag

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to declare dynamic meta content and try two different ways but its not working. kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

I am using the code like this

```
<meta name="description" content='<%#desc%>'/>
```

and

```
<meta name="description" content="<%=desc%>"/>
```

both the code not working, also declaring desc variable as public in my c# code

Comment: Where do you declare `desc`? Please post that code too.

Comment: desc declare in my .cs page public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string desc="Hello";

Answer (score 0):

That won't work as ASP.NET won't understand that the word you're providing is a variable or something else and it would leave it unused.

In ASP.NET the variables are used using `@` **at the rate of sign**. Then you can use this:

```
@{ 
   var desc = "This is the description";
}

/* and in the body part, use the variable as */

<meta name="description" content="@desc"/>
```

Now the `@desc` would be rendered as a variable. And you'll get the result.

You're probably new to the ASP.NET, you need to learn the syntax of the language first. Please refer to the following link:

http://www.asp.net/web-pages

Comment: thanks for your reply, trying the same but not working..shall we add in c# page

Comment: You can create the variable anywhere in your code. It would be preffered to use it inside the very page then access it using the `@`.

Comment: yes i am very new to asp.net, there using cshtml page but i am using simple aspx web form